# VS Code tyescript build task and node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am using latest install of VS Code (1.27.2)

When I build my typescript project, despite ignoring "node_modules" folder in my tsconfig file, the VS Code's build task is picking up a load of build problems with files from that directory.

Here is my tasks.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",       
"tasks":[
            {
                "type": "typescript",
                "tsconfig": "src\\tsconfig.json",
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$tsc"
                ],               
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                }              

            }
        ]
}
```

My project structure on disk looks like this:

`\.vscode
\dist
\node_modules
\src
\.gitignore
\.package.json`

My typescript files, including `tsconfig.json` are under the `\src` folder.

Here is the contents of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules/**/*",
        "**/node_modules/**/*",
        "node_modules",
        "../node_modules"
    ]     
}
```

As you can see I have tried to cover multiple possibilities with the exclude paths, because I am not sure what the root path is (is it the path of the tsconfig file itself? or the root folder of the project as opened in VSCode?

When I press `ctrl + shift + B` it triggers the build. In the problems window I see 92 errors. Here is an example of one:

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:732:9 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'stdout' must be of type 'WritableStream', but here has type 'WriteStream'.

732         stdout: WriteStream;
```

As you can see typescript seems to be building `d.ts` files from the node_modules folder, despite this being ignored in the tsconfig.

What am I going wrong?

(tsc --version
Version 3.1.1)

Comment: Probably, this problem connects to types collisions, but not with VSCode. To check this create new project only with @types/node and your setup. It should work fine. Then add package by package to find who fails your build.

Comment: It's not building them it is using them so that it can type check your code in `src`. `@types` supercede excludes. You can use `typeRoots` to override this

Comment: @AluanHaddad if you add that as an answer I will accept it - cheers